# Why this java code is showing strange behavior?

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve a competitive programming question, i have solved the question by my logic but i cant understand an output,

Whenever i enter 1 as input it shows output 0, instead of asking for an string input.

Here is the link to question:-[link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/practice-problems/algorithm/xsquare-and-palindromes-insertion/)

Here is the code:

```
    package Algorithms;// Working program using Reader Class

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MaxndSecodMax
{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = s.nextInt();


        for(int k=0;k<input;k++)
        {

            HashMap<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();
            String x = s.nextLine();
            String splitForm[] = x.split("");
            for(String s1: splitForm){
                if(hash.get(s1)!=null){
                    hash.put(s1, hash.get(s1)+1);
                }
                else{
                    hash.put(s1,1);
                }
            }

            checkEvenOdd(hash);

        }

    }

    private static void checkEvenOdd(HashMap<String, Integer> evenOdd){

        ArrayList<Integer> even =new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> odd =new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : evenOdd.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getValue()%2==0){
                even.add(entry.getValue());
            }
            else{
                odd.add(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        if(odd.size()!=0){
            System.out.println(odd.size()-1);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: x.split(""); seems wrong. Are you sure you want to split on "" ? (What is that supposed to do, I could not even find out reading the javadoc).

Comment: it would split all the char in the word, i.e mtisted=[m,t,i....] and so on

Comment: `int input = s.nextInt();` gets the next integer but doesn't clear the buffer. It therefore still has a newline in it which will be passed directly to `String x = s.nextLine();`

Comment: hmmmm..., i was thinking the same, but didnt know what to google, how can i avoide that.

Comment: Instead of calling `s.nextInt()`, use `s.nextLine()` and convert the returned string into an integer.

Comment: Thanks that worked :-), but won't it be a bit more inconvenient, like is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The java.util.Scanner.nextLine() method advances this scanner past the
>   current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method
>   returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at
>   the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

you should use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`, as nextLine gives the current line.